# visit a Full URL with parameter value

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script to send a GET requests

also I'm trying to provide a URL access after changing some parameter value

problem:
**when I hover over the link it will only underline URL without parameters values(check the following screen)**

when I entered the URL it will redirect me to:

`http://testphp.vulnweb.com/artists.php?artist=`

[image]

I'm wondering if there is a solution for this case or not

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is there an HTML script tag in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note that it's the terminal and not your script that decides what's considered part of a URL for the purpose of selecting or clicking.**

But what I can suggest is to Use the **URL encoding** for those special characters instead of explicit special characters:

```
%27 = Single Quote **'**
%3C = Less than **<**
%3E = More than **>**
```

For example

```
URL=http://testphp.vulnweb.com/artists.php?artist=
PARTIAL_URL=$URL%3Cscript%3E
```

That will be shown `http://testphp.vulnweb.com/artists.php?artist=<script>`
**Maybe** that would do the trick

Comment: do you know some commands in Linux to convert a string to URL encode?